# Highchart is not working with javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm using a Highchart code, and I'm having problems using my combobox update , they are not working at the same time (Highchart graphic and combobox)

When I hide the Highchart graphic my combobox update is working fine.

Here is the [Highchart graphic on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/)

Here are [my tables on SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4aa3f/1)

Here is my controller:

```
    def index
      @countries= Country.find(:all)
      @cities = City.find(:all,:condition=>['country_id =?',params[:country_id] ])
    end

    def update_cties
      @cities = City.find(:all,:conditions=>['country_id = ?',params[:country_id].to_i ] )

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {
            render :update do |page|
              page.replace_html("cities", :partial=>"cities")
            end
        }
    end 
end
```

Here is my partial view:

```
 Cities
 <%= select_tag "city_id",options_for_select(@cities.collect {|t| [t.name,t.id]} ,params[:city_id].to_i) %>
```

Here is my view:  "index.html.erb"

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% form_tag :controller=>"project",:action=>"index" do %>
        Select a country:
        <%= select_tag "country_id", "<option value=\"\">Select</option>"+options_for_select(@countries.collect {|t| [t.name,t.id]},params[:country_id].to_i),:onchange=>remote_function(:url=>{:controller=>"project",:action=>"update_cities"},:with=>"'country_id=' + $('country_id').value")  %>
        <div id="cities">
             <%= render :partial=>"cities" %>
        </div>

        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %> 
    <% end %>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

        }]
    });
});
```

Please somebody can help me with this?
I will really appreciate help

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle showing this?

Comment: Hello @wegeld I'm using this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/ but is not working when my combobox update (I mean combobox and higchart are not working at the same time).

Comment: Ok I understood if you hide the Highchart graphic your combobox is working but when is active your combobox won't update your cities.

Comment: @CarlitosMorales, a jsfiddle showing a sample of code that does not include the code you are trying to use (all of it) doesn't really show any issue or more info.

Comment: The rest of code is using rails and i think that won't show on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $.noConflict(); before you include new jquery plugin like below,

```
  //your old plugin here

   <script type="text/javascript">
     $.noConflict();
   </script>
```

Comment: Ok I tried your code, now my combobox is working but seems that the Highchart Graphic is not working. Seems that needs something else